# Compare two files for duplicates and send result to a third file

Tags: python, duplicates

2 files have to be checked:

1. File archive.txt includes archived usernames.
2. File import.txt includes usernames that have to be checked with archive.txt.
3. If the imported usernames are not included in archive.txt they should be saved to a third output file (new.txt)

I found some interesting code snippet, but it only compares and writes new entries directly into the file. I can't manage to write it to a third file.

Any ideas?

```html
    with open('./export/import.txt', 'r') as infile, open('./process/new.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        seen = set()
        for line in infile:
            for word in line.split():
                if word not in seen:
                    seen.add(word)
                    outfile.write('{}\n'.format(word))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help.

```
with open('./export/archive.txt', 'r') as archive, open('./export/import.txt', 'r') as importtxt, open('./export/new.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        toCheck = archive.read()
        for word in importtxt:
            if word not in toCheck:
                outfile.write('{}\n'.format(word))
```

This should help.

1. Read content of archive.txt
2. Iterate content of import.txt and validate if item in archive.txt
3. if item not found write to new.txt